# How to simplify this code (generates a random int between min and max base on unsigned int)?

Tags: c++, random

The code is

```
return min + static_cast<int>(static_cast<double>(max - min + 1.0) *
  (number / (UINT_MAX + 1.0)));
```

number is a random number obtained by rand_s. min and max are ints and represent minimum and maximum values (inclusive).

If you provide a solution not using unsigned int as a number, please also explain how to make it be random.

Please do not submit solutions using rand().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `static_cast<double>` is redundant because the "+1.0"s will cause promotion to double anyway.

Answer (score 3):

@[Andrew Stein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140786/how-to-simplify-this-code-generates-a-random-int-between-min-and-max-base-on-un#140826)

In Numerical Recipes in C: The Art of Scientific Computing (William H. Press, Brian P. Flannery, Saul A. Teukolsky, William T. Vetterling; New York: Cambridge University Press, 1992 (2nd ed., p. 277)), the following comments are made:

> "If you want to generate a random
>   integer between 1 and 10, you should
>   always do it by using high-order bits,
>   as in
>
> `j = 1 + (int) (10.0 * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)));`
>
> and never by
>   anything resembling
>
> `j = 1 + (rand() % 10);`
>
> (which uses lower-order bits)."

From `man 3 rand`

Comment: How about bit-reversing the input and then using the low-order bits ;-)

Comment: full bit-reversal is slow, he can just switch upper and lower halves of a 32-bit unsigned word w, as in ((w >> 16) | (w << 16))

Comment: The "don't use low bits" advice, as far as I know, applies mostly to linear congruential generators (such as rand()), where low bits are not very random. rand_s(), from what I understand, is not an LCG, and this doesn't apply.

Comment: Oh, I always assumed it was so that the over-represented outputs were almost-evenly spread through the range, rather than being clustered at the bottom and affecting the expected value...

Answer (score 1):

How about [Boost:Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/random/index.html)

Comment: Randandandom is even better ;)

Comment: It isn't allowed in some projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the arithmetic in an unsigned long long instead of a double, but only if ULONGLONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX*UINT_MAX, which is probably implementation defined. But if you're worried about that, you'd be worried about potential loss of precision in the original code in the case where (max - min) or RAND_MAX is large.

Whether the long long is actually faster might depend how good your platform's hardware float is. But integer arithmetic arguably is inherently simpler than floating-point.

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```
min + number % (max - min + 1)
```

Check the end-cases

Comment: NB. If (max - min + 1) is not an exact multiple of MAX_RAND then the number are not evenly distributed.

Comment: Agreed. I did presume that max-min is relatively small

Comment: @Martin York: that's OK, they aren't in the original code, either. And of course there's no way to make them be, short of using multiple inputs to generate multiple outputs,

Comment: This fails miserably when min is INT_MIN and max is INT_MAX. Then max - min + 1 equals 0, resulting in division by zero.

Comment: Like I said, presume that max - min is small. Say max is 1 and min is 6 for a dice roll...

Comment: As said in another answer, this is not a good general approach because the low order bits of many RNGs are less random than the high order bits.